# Pentaho - Execute a process - Accessing Output

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Execute a process step and am able to run the scripts that I need to run properly. However, I am not able to get the output from the script. Whenever I use the variable that has output in it, the value comes as empty.

Below are the steps and scripts that are used:

1. Execute a process calls a shell script (x.sh)
2. Shell script calls a python script (y.py) and returns the result
3. I need to process the result, which is where I am facing problem, as the result is always coming empty.

**Python Script:**

```
print('Manish')
```

**Shell script**

```
echo $(./y.py)
```

**Execute a process configuration**
[image]

After this step, when I log the output field, Result output, I am getting empty values.

I've tested the scripts by executing them directly and can see output, however the same is not happening when I am running them in pentaho.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Run SSH Command. In select step you get fields stdOut.

Example:
[image: example]

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Write to log** step after **Execute a process**:
[image: Transformation with log writing]

It is necessary to configure output fields in **Execute a process**:
[image: Execute process Output]

And then in **Write to log**:

[image: Write to log configuration]